# Visual studio debugger cannot find any identifier even though the symbols are loaded

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, symbols

I'm trying to debug a program in Visual Studio for which I have the symbols, but not the source code (it's a Unity game, the source in question is for the UnityPlayer.dll. I do have the source for the actual exe file). 
The symbols load correctly, I can break into the debugger and can see call stacks with function names, as I expect to.

However, when I try to add a function breakpoint, it does not work: the breakpoint gets added, but it shows a little error icon in the Breakpoint window, and it's never hit.

If I double-click on a stack frame, I can get to the disassembly window, and the "Address" bar correctly shows the function name. However, if I try to enter *any* symbol name in the bar - including just copying the one it's *already* showing - I get an error message saying "identifier "whatever" is undefined". It's as if some part of Visual Studio is not aware of the loaded symbols.

One suspicious thing I noticed is that in the call stack window, all frames not in the actual exe file are shown with the "Unknown" language. I have no idea what is causing this.

Here's a picture to hopefully make this a little clearer: [image]

What can I do to fix this, or at least work around the issue somehow? I've encountered this on VS 2017 and tried updating it to the latest version, and installing VS 2019, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

Notice in the names it's showing you, you get the parameter types too. Like, it's showing you `FMOD_OS_Time_Sleep(unsigned int)` and not just `FMOD_OS_Time_Sleep`. This is because the name is mangled, random looking characters are added on either side of the name to encode how many parameters it takes, and what types those parameters are.

One possibility is that it's expecting you to put in the mangled representation of the name. You can also try putting in the name exactly as it appears in the call stack, I would try both with `UnityPlayer.dll!` and without. Failing that, run `strings` on the dll to get the mangled representation of the function name and try that.